# Image is not loaded using Glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I have a vector image. If I want to set the image to ImageView, the picture is not loaded.

code:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.vector_image).into(imageView)
```

However, when I use:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.vector_image))
```

and it is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are loading a vector drawable which Glide does not support yet.

Answer (score 3):

Glide doesn't support vector drawables yet. So implementing vector drawables you have to do yourself.
For reference you can check below links for this issue reported by developers on github:

[link 1](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1419)
[link 2](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1267)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.vector_image)
    .into(imageView);
```

**EDIT**

You can also use it like this as mentioned on issue

```
Glide.with(mContext) .load("") .error(R.drawable.vector_image) .into(imageView);
```

Comment: This wont work either, Glide does not support Vector drawable.

Comment: yes . i just found an issue at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/794 . According to this you can use something like this
Glide.with(mContext) .load("") .error(R.drawable.vector_image) .into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

Try this this working fine.

```
Glide.with(GlideActivity.this).load(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .fitCenter().into(imageview);
```